# Vertical-align not working with XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype?

Tags: css, image, doctype, vertical-alignment

Okay, so I messed around for a long time trying to center an image vertically within a div using vertical-align:middle (while also centering it horizontally with text-align:center) and I was wracking my brains trying to figure out why in the world it wasn't working.

```
.container{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:200px;
    }

    .image{
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

It looked to me like it should, but it didn't, turns out that the thing that solved it was changing the doctype from

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
```

When I do that, the image is centered.

How come? I was under impression that the strict doctype allows less attributes than the transitional one, is that wrong? I can't seem to find any information regarding vertical-align and XHTML 1.0 Transitional, when it comes to Strict however I find all kinds of information about it not allowing this and that, so I'm a bit confused. I'd rather not use Strict for this particular site, but I do need to use vertical-align.

Can anybody shed some light on this please? Thanks

Comment: Which browsers have you tried this on? Did you put anything else on your document (like an `<?xml` declaration) before the doctype? Anything before the doctype will trigger browsers' _quirks modes_, which are quite a hell. Also, could you share the fragment of html code with the image? Also, screenshots of what you are getting and what you are trying to get would help (vertical-align is a very obscure property that works differently from what most people expect).

Comment: @herenvardo - anything before the doctype only triggers quirks in IE, not modern browsers. Modern browsers also know what to do with the XML declaration you mention. IE does not.

Comment: @Rob: which is even worse: entirely different modes on different browsers instead of just different quirks? It may do if you are aiming to hack IE anyway, but not very advisable. Still, it would be quite useful to see exactly what the OP is trying to achieve, and on which browser/s it is failing. And looking again at it, there is a chunk of the doctype missing from the quotes: if the problem is in that chunk, we won't be able to point it out.

Comment: @Herman: Another thought: what the Strict doctypes disable is deprecated and considered bad practice anyway; so if your site can work with them, then there is no reason to stick to Transitional. Transitional was intended to ease transition (from 3.2 insane tag-soup), Strict is more "what modern HTML is supposed to do", with the oversight of the target attribute (which is quite valuable on pages with iframes, but Strict doesn't allow).

Comment: @herenvardo - I've tried it in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and Explorer and the same thing happens in all of them. I tried to isolate the problem by creating a new document, so the HTML is very simple `<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="image.png"/>
  </div>` The CSS is what you see in my first post, the only difference between the two files is the doctype.

Comment: Tried to post images but the site won't let me because my reputation is too low.

Comment: Unbelievable how many hours this just cost me. vertical-align: middle simply wouldn't work and switching doctypes was definitely not the first, nor the 10th on my mind..

Answer (score 0):

The doctype does not affect what CSS does. However, the second doctype you tried does trigger quirks mode which you don't want to be in because it uses the wrong box model. New web pages should not be using transitional doctypes either. Always use strict or the newer doctype: `<!doctype html>`

Comment: It works with `<!doctype html>`, it also works with XHTML 1.1 Strict.

Comment: I guess I'll just go with another doctype then, though I'm still confused as to why the Strict doctype allows vertical-align when the Transitional doesn't, I would've expected it to be the other way around.

Comment: @ChrisBosco - A simple reading of the W3C spec or inspection using any browsers debugger will show you that's not true.

Comment: Thanks for making me look that up again (removed my comment). I think what I meant was the "[almost standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko's_Almost_Standards_Mode)" but I agree if possible always work in strict html5 so this isn't even a consideration. I took issue with "The doctype does not affect what CSS does."