# Image not aligning inside div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am able to align image in middle vertically inside `DIV` when i do it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/187/) but same is not working when i do it on the website it seems it is conflicting with some CSS which i am not able to locate.

I am using the same CSS which i used for the jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/QHEnL/187/), On actual website logo always come aligned at top position.

I would appreciate help in this regarding.

**Solution**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var h = $("#BannerSlider").height();
        $.map($("#BannerSlider img"), function (e) {
            var top = (h - $(e).height()) / 2;
            $(e).css("margin-top", top);
        });
    });
</script> 
    <title></title>
    <style>
.SponsorLogos
{
    width:600px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:60px;
    min-height:550px;
    background:red;
}
.SponsorLogoWrapper
{
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border:1px solid #78AC1B;
    line-height:160px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;

}
.SponsorLogoWrapper img
{
    display: inline-block;
    border:0px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <div class="SponsorLogos">

          <div id="BannerSlider" class="SponsorLogoWrapper" >
               <img src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/images/01.jpg" width="88" height="126" alt="image"/>
               </div>
         <div id="BannerSlider" class="SponsorLogoWrapper" >
                <img src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/images/02.jpg" width="88" height="110" alt="image" />
                 </div>
        <div id="BannerSlider" class="SponsorLogoWrapper" >
                <img src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/images/03.jpg" width="88" height="100" alt="image"/>
                       </div>
         <div id="BannerSlider" class="SponsorLogoWrapper" >
                <img src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/images/04.jpg" width="88" height="126" alt="image"/>
                       </div>
        <div id="BannerSlider" class="SponsorLogoWrapper" >
                <img src="http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/images/05.jpg" width="88" height="90" alt="image"/>
           </div>
</div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switch the jsFiddle DOCTYPE to match your websites the images align to the top again (you can do this in the *info* panel on the left).

With that in mind you could check this answer: [Vertical-align not working with XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506910/vertical-align-not-working-with-xhtml-1-0-transitional-doctype)

**Response to first comment**

Well the easiest thing to do would be to change the DOCTYPE.
If you can't do that then you need to find another method entirely. Vertical align works best with tables so you could change the `display` props to be table based. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/64UnS/1/

I don't know if you'll be able to implement this - browser support varies. Of course you are using `display: inline-block;` already and I didn't see an IE7 fallback so maybe this is fine for you.

Other options could include:

- making your images *160 x 160px*
- changing the markup so that the each image is output as a
  `background-image` inline on the `<a />` tag. This is then easy to
  center (of course you'll need to be sure of your image dimensions -
  `background-size` support is even less well supported)
- using a javascript solution (I see you hav jQuery in the `<head />`
  already)

Hope that helps!

Comment: lengthened my answer with some options. Let me know if you want to pursue any one in particular

Comment: I managed to get it working using jQuery, I will add that part of code to the basic Question

Comment: I will mark your solution as correct as it is also works & is creative as we don't need to use jQuery for this

Comment: That's great and thanks for posting the jQuery you used as well - helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the actual website uses the XHTML transitional doctype and JS fiddle uses the HTML5 (html) doctype.

Comment: You can change the doctype by Clicking on 'Info' in jsFiddle and changing it via the DTD dropdown list.