# Vertical Align working in fiddle, but not in browser

Tags: html, css

No scripts or anything, just pure CSS and HTML.

Working in Dreamweaver and Chrome. I am having issues vertically aligning an image in the middle of a div, so I created a fiddle to post here, but the fiddle actually aligns the image vertically in the center. So a bit confused on what is going on with this. It even works here in the code snippet, but I open the file in my browser and it just doesn't work.

**[Here is the live example of this issue.](http://www.metsales.com/metropolitansales/webinars/Honeywell-Webinar-LP.html)** There is no difference in code between the fiddle, the code snippet and the live form.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.webinar-header {
  background: #00A9FF;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;

}
.webinar-header-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.webinar-header-logo img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="webinar-header">
  <div class="webinar-header-logo">
    <img src="http://www.metsales.com/metropolitansales/webinars/images/Metsales-webinar-lp-header.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What 'float' is for?

Comment: Positioning the image all the way to the left. I suppose that's not necessary, but will that effect the vertical align?

Comment: @Adjit ^Yes it will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from your `.webinar-header-logo` style.

There is no need for it, at least in the markup you posted

Answer (score 1):

It's the `float:left`. You're already `position:relative` so you can remove your `margin:left;` and `float:left`.

```
.webinar-header-logo {
/* float: left; */
height: 75px;
line-height: 34px;
left: 45px;
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to style your div with: 
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;

Comment: it is in the second div - `.webinar-header-logo`

Answer (score 0):

There was a difference in your example and your snippet. To fix your site's code you should use `display: inline-block` and `height:100%`. This was answered quite well on this post:

[How to vertically align an image inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.webinar-header {
  background: #00A9FF;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 75px;

}
.webinar-header-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 75px;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 75px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.webinar-header img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="webinar-header">
  <img src="http://www.metsales.com/metropolitansales/webinars/images/Metsales-webinar-lp-header.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `!DOCTYPE` on your site.

Change from:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

… to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

See [Vertical-align not working with XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506910/vertical-align-not-working-with-xhtml-1-0-transitional-doctype)